# nlohmann json version 3.2.0, runtime error

Tags: json, c++11

I have several json files from a game I am modding that I want to be able to process using an external application.

as far as I can tell this code is within the specifications but I get a runtime error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::type_error'
what():  [json.exception.type_error.304] cannot use at() with string
```

this is the stripped code to reproduce the error:

```
#include "json.hpp"
using json = nlohmann::json;
using namespace std;

namespace ns
{
class info
{
public:
    std::string id;
};
void to_json(json& j, const info& mi);
void from_json(const json& j, info& mi);
}

int main()
{
    json j ="[{\"id\": \"identifier\"}]";

    ns::info info = j;
    return 0;
}

void ns::to_json(json& j, const ns::info& mi)
{
    j = json{
        {"id",mi.id},
    };
}
void ns::from_json(const json& j, ns::info& mi)
{
    mi.id = j.at("id").get<std::string>();
}
```

and here is the compiler output:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in jsontest (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -std=c++11 -fexceptions -g  -c C:\Users\UserOne\Documents\c++\jsontest\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\jsontest.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
Output file is bin\Debug\jsontest.exe with size 2.82 MB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `json j = "...";` initializes j with a JSON *string* value. It doesn't try to parse the contents. For that, you need to make it a json literal instead: `json j = "..."_json;`
2. After fixing that, you have a JSON *array* and but you're trying to access a field of a JSON *object* in `ns::from_json()`.

So, fix both of those:

```
json j ="{\"id\": \"identifier\"}"_json;
```

and it'll work.

You might also consider using raw strings to avoid escaping all the quotes:

```
json j = R"({"id": "identifier"})"_json;
```

or just using an initializer list instead of parsing a string of json:

```
json j = { {"id", "identifier" } };
```

And if your source is a string being provided as a function argument or whatever, instead of a literal known at compile time:

```
std::string s = R"({"id": "identifier"})";
json j = json::parse(s);
```

Comment: I thought I had tried "json::parse()" but apparently that was in fact the problem. I thought however JSON was internally literally a string as it is in a file. What is it that it is parsing?

Comment: Getting this error instead:

    [json.exception.type_error.304] cannot use at() with array.

Following the same logic I refrenced the first element of the array and assigned it to a new json object and it seemed to fix it.
Am I doing this right?

json jo = j[0];

Comment: @CatOfBlades See item 2 in the answer.

Comment: the reason I have the string literal as an array is because that's how the json file I am trying to load appears. I don't know how or why the developer of the game engine wrote the code to write the file that way but it has strings and two lists of strings inside a "[{ .. }]" and I wasn't aware that the [] part would prevent me from processing it as I normally would.